# Count how many list entries have a string property that ends with a particular char

Tags: java, string, char

I have an array list with some names inside it (first and last names). What I have to do is go through each "first name" and see how many times a character (which the user specifies) shows up at the end of every first name in the array list, and then print out the number of times that character showed up.

```
public int countFirstName(char c) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Name n : list) {
        if (n.getFirstName().length() - 1 == c) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

That is the code I have. The problem is that the counter (`i`) doesn't add 1 even if there is a character that matches the end of the first name.

Comment: Write commets in your code, of the algorithm you expect your code to follow, then check that the code actually implements the algorithm..

Comment: you compare the length of the first name with `c`. Although `c` is a `char`, it can be implicitly converted to an `int`. So basically, your logic is messed up.

Comment: @Turing85 ohh thanks! I will try and fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the index of last character in the string to the required character, instead of the last character itself, which you can access with [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

```
String firstName = n.getFirstName()
if (firstName.charAt(firstName.length() - 1) == c) {
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! I spent hours trying to figure it out myself! (Your solution worked) :D

Comment: **NOTE** : _It will throw exception for empty String._

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting out learning to code, there is a great value in using pencil and paper, or describing your algorithm ahead of time, in the language you think in. Most people that learn a foreign language start out by assembling a sentence in their native language, translating it to foreign, then speaking the foreign. Few, if any, learners of a foreign language are able to think in it natively

Coding is no different; all your life you've been speaking English and thinking in it. Now you're aiming to learn a different pattern of thinking, syntax, key words. This task will go a lot easier if you:

- work out in high level natural language what you want to do first
- write down the steps in clear and simple language, like a recipe
- don't try to do too much at once

Had I been a tutor marking your program, id have been looking for something like this:

```
//method to count the number of list entries ending with a particular character
public int countFirstNamesEndingWith(char lookFor) {
  //declare a variable to hold the count
  int cnt = 0;

  //iterate the list 
  for (Name n : list) {

    //get the first name
    String fn = n.getFirstName();

    //get the last char of it
    char lc = fn.charAt(fn.length() - 1);

    //compare
    if (lc == lookFor) {
        cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Taking the bullet points in turn:

The comments serve as a high level description of what must be done. We write them aLL first, before even writing a single line of code. My course penalised uncommented code, and writing them first was a handy way of getting the requirement out of the way (they're a chore, right? Not always, but..) but also it is really easy to write a logic algorithm in high level language, then translate the steps into the language learning. I definitely think if you'd taken this approach you wouldn't have made the error you did, as it would have been clear that the code you wrote didn't implement the algorithm you'd have described earlier

Don't try to do too much in one line. Yes, I'm sure plenty of coders think it looks cool, or trick, or shows off what impressive coding smarts they have to pack a good 10 line algorithm into a single line of code that uses some obscure language features but one day it's highly likely that someone else is going to have to come along to maintain that code, improve it or change part of what it does - at that moment it's no longer cool, and it was never really a smart thing to do

Aominee, in their comment, actually gives us something like an example of this:

```
return (int)list.stream().filter(e -> e.charAt.length()-1)==c).count();
```

It's a one line implementation of a solution to your problem. Cool huh? Well, it has a bug* (for a start) but it's not the main thrust of my argument. At a more basic level: *have you got any idea what it's doing?* can you look at it and in 2 seconds tell me how it works?

It's quite an advanced language feature, it's trick for sure, but it might be a very poor solution because it's hard to understand, hard to maintain as a result, and does a lot while looking like a little- it only really makes sense if you're well versed in the language. This one line bundles up a facility that loops over your list, a feature that effectively has a tiny sub method that is called for every item in the list, and whose job is to calculate if the name ends with the sought char

It p's a brilliant feature, a cute example and it surely has its place in production java, but it's place is probably not here, in your learning exercise

Similarly, I'd go as far to say that this line of yours:

```
    if (n.getFirstName().length() - 1 == c) {
```

Is approaching "doing too much" - I say this because it's where your logic broke down; you didn't write enough code to effectively implement the algorithm. You'd actually have to write even more code to implement this way:

```
    if (n.getFirstName().charAt(n.getFirstName().length() - 1) == c) {
```

This is a right eyeful to load into your brain and understand. The accepted answer broke it down a bit by first getting the name into a temporary variable. That's a sensible optimisation. I broke it out another step by getting the last char into a temp variable. In a production system I probably wouldn't go that far, but this is your learning phase - try to minimise the number of operations each of your lines does. It will aid your understanding of your own code a great deal

If you do ever get a penchant for writing as much code as possible in as few chars, look at some code golf games here on the stack exchange network; the game is to abuse as many language features as possible to make really short, trick code.. pretty much every winner stands as a testament to condense that should never, ever be put into a production system maintained by normal coders who value their sanity

*the bug is it doesn't get the first name out of the Name object